# How to name my json object array in asp.net core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am trying to name my array of objects, but it lists only the result of the array being created:

```
public class Listagem {
    public List<Captura> captura { get; set; }
}
```

my class

```
public class Captura {
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string FotoURL { get; set; } 
}
```

my controller

```
public IactionResult(Listagem models) {

var resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(models.captura);

...
```

Current results:

```
[
   {
     "Cod":11111,
     "photo":xxxx,
```

Expected outcome:

```
{
   "captura":[
   {
     "Cod":11111,
     "photo":xxxx,
```

Comment: What is `models`?  Is it of type `Listagem` or something else?  If of type `Listagem` did you try `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(captura);`?

Comment: models is the name of the object I instantiated from my Listagem class, to access its attributes and methods.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
    var resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(models.captura);
```

but you want

```
    var resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(models);
```

Type names don't matter. Local variable names don't matter. The contents of the expression used to get the argument to `SerializeObject` doesn't matter. Only member names matter.

Most likely, you wrote the above because you have other stuff in `models` you don't want serialized. In this case, you should do

```
public class CapturaModel {
    public IList<Captura> captura;
};


    //...
    var resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new CapturaModel { captura = models.captura; });
```

This code also shows why the contents of the expression used get the argument to `SerializeObject` doesn't matter.